kdb/q How to change command line input to type integer?
I'm getting some values as part of my command line input:
input:.z.x;
first_number: input 0;
second_number: input 1;

The type of the first_number and second_number variables is a string. However, I want to be able to cast to integer.
I tried this: "i"$first_number but it's giving me a type error:
q))"i"$first_number
'type
  [5]  "i"$first_number
          ^

I was wondering if anyone here can shed some light on how to change the type of the command line input so that the two variables are integers. Thanks for your inputs.

You could also make use of .Q.def and .Q.opt to parse cmd line args into certain datatypes (with defaults):
C:\Users\tlynch\>q -arg1 1 -arg2 abc
KDB+ 4.0 2021.02.02 Copyright (C) 1993-2021 Kx Systems

q)
q).Q.def[`arg1`arg2`arg3!(0j;`;.z.D)].Q.opt .z.x
arg1| 1
arg2| `abc
arg3| 2024.04.10

See https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zx-argv

You want "I"$ to parse the string to an integer
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/tok/.
Lower case i is a cast and will only work on other numeric types.  https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cast/
